# Phonegap 2.5.0 splashscreen shifts down during display

Tags: ios, cordova

After updating Phonegap from 2.3.0 to 2.5.0, the splashscreen in my iOS/iPhone app makes a strange 20px shift downwards during app launch. First it positions itself behind the status bar but soon drops below it 20px lower. This also happens in Phonegap default template. In previous versions of Phonegap I did not experience this problem. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with the 20px shift if I included the Status Bar which I wanted to do. To resolve the issue I edited the file CDVSplashScreen.m and I changed the following line:

_imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _imageView.image.size.width, _imageView.image.size.height);

TO:

_imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, **-20**, _imageView.image.size.width, _imageView.image.size.height);

I tested on my iPhone 4 and 5 as well as the Simulator for a regular iPhone and it appears to have done the trick.

Comment: Although this works, the drawback is you'll have to remember to make that same edit to CDVSplashScreen.m every time you update Cordova. 

You might play with adding the call

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];`

to your main UIViewController class.

Comment: I also found this information, related to what you suggested. My learning continues :) http://cookieflow.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/hiding-and-showing-the-ios-status-bar-in-phonegap-2-5-0/

Answer (score 2):

You can also update your project to the 2.6.0 version. This issue is know for cordova 2.5. I had the same problem and I just update it to correct it

Comment: Yes, I did that already, when the 2.6.0 version came (after my initial question). This is certainly the best solution. Thanks for reminding it here too!

Answer (score 1):

In your XCode target, there is a section for iPhone Deployment info. The Status Bar section of that panel has a Visibility checkbox to hide the status bar during launch. That should prevent the 20px shift you're seeing between iOS launch and Cordova readiness.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, and the shift does not appear any more, but now the status bar does not appear at all anymore? I need it to be visible after the launch. How to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

1) **hide status bar**

In XCode 4.6, select your project, then the Summary tab, then check the "Hide during application launch" checkbox.

2) **show status bar** again when the app has finished loading. You can do that by calling:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

3) You may also need to resize your webview frame if the webview is partially hidden behind the status bar:

```
CGRect r = webView.frame;    
r.size.height -= 20;
r.origin.y = 20;    
webView.frame = r;
```

I created a simple Phonegap plugin for this which I call right after the deviceready event is fired in javascript (you can access your webview from the plugin at *super.webview*).